# Enable Child Component trough Parent from Another Child

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation, angular5

my angular-foundation project is structured as:
[Structur project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnjKV.png)

If i want show child component (menu1-item-edit) inside parent (menu1) from other child (menu1-item). How can i do it?
In menu1.component.html i set menu1-item-edit component with this code:

```
 <div class="row">
  <app-menu1-item-edit *ngIf="edit_item"></app-menu1-item-edit>
</div>
```

And menu1.component.ts code is:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Menu1ListaService} from './menu1Lista.service';
import {Menu1Item} from './menu1.model';
import {Menu1ItemEditComponent} from './menu1-item-edit/menu1-item-edit.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu1',
  templateUrl: './menu1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu1.component.scss'],
})
export class Menu1Component implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(Menu1ItemEditComponent ) child : Menu1ItemEditComponent ;

  listaMenu1: Menu1Item[] = null;
  mostratutto: boolean = false;
  boxeslista: string;
  titoloclass: string;
  edit_item: boolean = false;


  constructor(private serverGetMenuLista: Menu1ListaService ) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.GetElencoItemMenu1();
  }

  GetElencoItemMenu1() {

    if (!this.mostratutto) {
      this.serverGetMenuLista.getListaVetrina()
        .subscribe(
          (elencoitem: any[]) => this.listaMenu1 = elencoitem.splice(0, 20),
          (error) => console.log(error)
        );

      this.mostratutto = true;

    } else {

      this.mostratutto = false;

      this.serverGetMenuLista.getListaVetrina()
        .subscribe(
          (elencoitem: any[]) => this.listaMenu1 = elencoitem,
          (error) => console.log(error)
        );
    }


  }


}
```

The problem is setting true the variable "edit_item" from child component (menu1-item).

The code of menu1-item.component.html is:

```
<div class="blocco_vetrina_wrap" (click)="visualizzaDettagli(itemmenu1.ID)">
  <img
    [src]="itemmenu1.ImgQuaSmall"
    alt="{{ itemmenu1.Nome }}" title="{{ itemmenu1.Nome }}"
    class="thumbnail">
  <div class="blocco_vetrina_text">
    {{itemmenu1.Nome}}<i class="right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

And code of menu1-item.component.ts is:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {Menu1Item} from '../menu1.model';
import {Menu1Component} from '../menu1.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu1-item',
  templateUrl: './menu1-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu1-item.component.scss']
})
export class Menu1ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() itemmenu1: Menu1Item;

  @Output() abilitaEditItem = new EventEmitter<boolean>();


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  visualizzaDettagli(ID: number) {
    alert('ID: ' + ID);
    this.abilitaEditItem.next(true);
  }

}
```

Code of menu1-item-edit.component.html is simple:

```
<h1>MENU' EDIT TEST</h1>
```

And menu1-item-edit.component.ts is:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu1-item-edit',
  templateUrl: './menu1-item-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu1-item-edit.component.scss']
})
export class Menu1ItemEditComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

How cold i make the hid and show from menu1-item component ?
Thanks
Very much!!
Cristian Capannini

Comment: I just don't understand in which file is this piece of code

`<div class="row">
  <app-menu1-item-edit *ngIf="edit_item"></app-menu1-item-edit>
</div>`

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, thanks for following my topic. Ehm the piece is in menu1.component.html. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to **emit an event from the child** `menu1-item` (as you already do), **handle the event** with the parent and the handler will **set the variable** `edit_item` **to true**.

For handling the event you have to do something like this:

In **menu1-item.component.ts** change the method as follow:

```
visualizzaDettagli(id: number) {
    alert('ID: ' + id);
    abilitaEditItem.emit(true);
}
```

With this code you just send an event to the parent, now for handling it you have to capture it in the parent as follow:

**menu1.component.html**

```
<app-menu1-item (abilitaEditItem)="handlerMethod($event)">
```

**menu1.component.ts**

```
handlerMethod(enableEditItem: boolean) {
    edit_item = enableEditItem;
}
```

Comment: Edited the question with the proper changes that you have to do to your code!

Comment: thanks Lorenzo! sorry but angular is my new programming language and i come from asp.net (no mvc).....

Comment: No problem at all!! Always happy to help (and best if he/she is italian like me) ;) if you can, give me an "up" too!! Thanks!

Comment: sorry what is "up" here? :D

Comment: it's a "like", on the left of the answer there are 2 arrows with a number in center (actually is 0), 1 up and 1 down. When an answer is correct or helped you, in usually good to select "up". Ad if is totally incorrect press "down" and comment why was incorrect.